# How to remove grey bar at bottom of my android app?

Tags: android

For some reason, there is a grey bar at the bottom of my app:

[image: my app]
I can't seem to get rid of it.

Here is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="be.valuya.comptaplan.mobile.ComptaPlanMobileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_compta_plan_mobile" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="be.valuya.comptaplan.mobile.ComptaPlanMobileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_compta_plan_mobile">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Your `RelativeLayout` has a `paddingBottom` attr set. Maybe that's doing it? Also, you have an insane amount of redundant attributes in there.

Comment: decrease this  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its simple . Actually `@dimen` values plays vital role in here .

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

You can set value **"0dp"** in here `activity_vertical_margin` or Just  Remove this line.

AND

**CoordinatorLayout** : set height and width as `fill_parent`

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to fix it yet.

Comment: remove `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: thanks, I just found that somewhere and tried it out, so removing it didn't help.

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `AppBarLayout`

Comment: CoordinatorLayout set height and width as `fill_parent`

Answer (score 1):

assign them as `0dp` in your **dimens.xml**, or remove these attributes from your layout. or adjust all paddings equally.

```
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to fix it yet.

Comment: your appbar layout has android:layout_height="wrap_content" can you change it to fill_parent?

Answer (score 1):

Try and replace the value of `android:paddingBottom` inside your layout xml to `0dp`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="be.valuya.comptaplan.mobile.ComptaPlanMobileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_compta_plan_mobile">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck :-(

Comment: Can you please try it Linear layout like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

why you need weight in your layout??
 i made some changes try that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="be.valuya.comptaplan.mobile.ComptaPlanMobileActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_compta_plan_mobile">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and put in dimen folder

```
 <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

your activity.xml have to be like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_compta_plan_mobile" />
```

Comment: @ymajoros can you post your whole activity.xml file??

Comment: @ymajoros check i made some changes

Comment: in activity.xml  use it as `match_parent`

Comment: @ymajoros did u checked??